# Reorder divs and place them in two columns with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have some markup with boxes that I want in one column in a small breakpoint. When scaling up i want them in two columns and also rearrange the order.

Sketch for small screen:
http://niklasholmberg.se/temp/1.png

Sketch for larger screen:
http://niklasholmberg.se/temp/2.png

All of the boxes is of variable unknown height. I tried this with my limited knowledge of flexbox. I only got it working when setting a height of my outer container wrapping the four boxes. This is something I don't want to do.

Here's my flexbox code:
http://niklasholmberg.se/temp/testflex.html

Is this possible to achieve with flexbox or is there another way around it? Preferably without any js swapping the markup around.

Thanks

Comment: Voting to close with reason:  **"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*.**" "In the question itself" is important;  the links are all dead now, so later readers have no idea what the code at hand was.

Comment: URLs are returning a 404

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using flexbox:

```css
.main{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-flow: space-between;
}

.item {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 45%;
  background-color: rgb(255,150,100);
}
```

```html
<h4>Change the width of the browser.</h4>
<div class="main">
  <div class="item item1">1</div>
  <div class="item item2">2<br/>2</div>
  <div class="item item3">3<br/>3<br/>3</div>
  <div class="item item4">4<br/>4<br/>4<br/>4</div>
</div>
```